# Can I use bulb mode on a Nikon D90 without having to hold down the shutter button?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d90

Is there a way to get the bulb mode on the D90 to open the shutter when I press the shutter release button, and to close it again when I press the button for the second time, rather than having to hold the button down ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

If you get the [Nikon MC-DC2](http://www.nikonusa.com/Find-Your-Nikon/Product/Remote-Cords/25395/MC-DC2-Remote-Release-Cord-%281-meter%29.html) cable release, the button can be locked in place until you release it. For bulb exposures, I'd recommend a cable release to avoid shake and blurring in your result anyways, you're almost assured to do that with your hand on the camera directly.

Answer (score 4):

Wireless one is good too.

[http://www.amazon.com/Nikon-Wireless-Control-Digital-Cameras/dp/B00007EDZG/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=electronics&qid=1281804189&sr=8-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00007EDZG)

When i bought it, it was actually cheaper than the wired one.  Gotta aim it directly at the camera front though.

Comment: Can it open the shutter on the first button press and close it on the second, or do I  have to have my finger on the button all the time ?

Comment: @jfoucher The shutter will stay open until you press the button a second time.